# Is liblber part of openLDAP? What is it's purpose?

Tags: openldap

I see that liblber is a separate package BUT searching for it, what it is, why it is needed - is never answered. Only lots off questions/comments/etc on OpenLDAP.

So, my two questions:

1. is liblber contained within OpenLDAP? If yes, that may explain why it does not seem to have it's own project page.
2. What is liblber for - what does it do? as it is seems to be presented seperately of the openLDAP - even though it seems one would never not find one without the other (more simply - What does it do? Why would I want it? And please do not say - it supports openLDAP (how does it support it, if it supports it)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Yes, it's part of OpenLDAP.

(2) It implements the LDAP version of [ASN.1 Basic Encoding Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#BER_encoding). OpenLDAP ships with documentation for this library; possibly you need to install a -dev package to get it. For example, the [`lber-encode(3)` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/libldap2-dev/lber-encode.3.en.html). Unless you are a C/C++ programmer who needs to deal with LDAP, this library will probably be of little interest to you.

Comment: Thx. I’ll mark you as answer when possible. Seems I must wait a bit. I was looking for info on liblber to determine if I would include it in my apr-util packaging.